# Problems with importing existing mongodb to Atlas

Tags: mongodb, command-line

Just finished setting up my mongodb and found out that there is a free service called Atlas. Started up a cluster and ran a mongodump and mongorestore as explained here https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/atlas-on-day-one-importing-data, but can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my shell commands:

```
mongorestore --ssl --db=infovis --host infovis-shard-00-00-nmctc.mongodb.net:27017,infovis-shard-00-01-nmctc.mongodb.net:27017,infovis-shard-00-02-nmctc.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=Infovis-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --dir=dump/infovis --username danielbook --password <Password>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Solved the problem by running mongoimport on the server instead.

Comment: What specific version of `mongorestore` are you running (i.e. `mongorestore --version`) and what is the error message or output of the command when you try to run it?

Comment: There is no actual error message, it runs in the terminal with no output. Solved the problem though by doing running mongimport instead.

Comment: If you could solve the problem running `mongoimport`, your backup must be in a text format (i.e. as created by `mongoexport`) rather than the binary format of `mongodump`. If you want to post your solution as an answer, you should include more elaboration on the actual steps you took to backup & restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I solved this by using `mongoimport` instead. I had just created the database in mongo, so I could just use the same csv files and then use

`mongoimport -h cluster0-shard-00-00-nmctc.mongodb.net:27017 -d infovis -c flights -u <USER> -p <PASSWORD> --file march_2016.csv --type csv --headerline`

for each file I want to import to the Atlas database.